# Mongodb authentication issue

Tags: python, mongodb, authentication

I am new to **mongodb** and I am trying to connect it **remotely** (from my local system to live db) and it is connected successfully. I have admin users in admin table and want that without authentication no one can access my database. But when I try to connect Mongodb remotely via the below mention code , even without authentication i can access any db :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, Connection

c = MongoClient('myip',27017)

a = c.mydb.testData.find()
```

In my config file , the parameter auth is set to True , `auth = True` . But still no authentication is needed to access my db . Please can anyone let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Make sure authentication is enabled. Connect to the database and run the [getCmdLineOpts command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/) and check that authentication is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I would guess you haven't actually enabled authentication.  In order to enable authentication you must start the Mongo server with certain settings.  You can find more information below:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Basically you need to run with --auth in order to enable authentication.

Comment: I have looked at the link you provide but can you clarify me one thing what is this key file ? I mean this key file is the live server .pem file or user system file or anything else . I didn't get this key file actually

Comment: The key file is not strictly necessary for auth.  The link above includes it as an example but there are other ways to enable auth linked to from that page.  This page may be more what you are looking for: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authorization/#authorization

Comment: I am trying to restart my mongodb with auth but that gives me the error `ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
` command used `mongod --auth --config stack/mongodb/mongodb.conf` . FYI my server is using Bitnami

Comment: Sorry, not sure what could be the problem.  Perhaps the logs will give you an idea about what the error was.